# Concatenate data in a single row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
    TicketID                                Type       Code
    44899B82-41C9-4020-9C2B-007C6000D283    ARTI     22150012
    44899B82-41C9-4020-9C2B-007C6000D283    ARTI     22150017
    44899B82-41C9-4020-9C2B-007C6000D283    CASH     NULL
    76C6D696-55E7-4CA5-A1AA-0F0DB446D9A4    ARTI     22150018
    76C6D696-55E7-4CA5-A1AA-0F0DB446D9A4    ARTI     22150012
    76C6D696-55E7-4CA5-A1AA-0F0DB446D9A4    ARTI     22150011
    76C6D696-55E7-4CA5-A1AA-0F0DB446D9A4    CASH     NULL
```

And I want the following result:

```
    TicketID                                Type       Code
    44899B82-41C9-4020-9C2B-007C6000D283    ARTI     22150012, 22150017
    44899B82-41C9-4020-9C2B-007C6000D283    CASH     NULL
    76C6D696-55E7-4CA5-A1AA-0F0DB446D9A4    ARTI     22150018, 22150012, 22150011 
    76C6D696-55E7-4CA5-A1AA-0F0DB446D9A4    CASH     NULL
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Been asked SO many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must concatenate those values. The best way is to use `FOR XML PATH`.

#### Query ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8812c6/2/0)):

```
SELECT [TicketID], [Type]
    , [Code] = stuff(
        (
            SELECT ', '+ [Code] 
            FROM data d2
            WHERE [TicketID] = d1.[TicketID] AND [Type] = d1.[Type]
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, ''
    ) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [TicketID], [Type] FROM data) d1
```

#### Output:

```
TicketID                                Type    Code
44899B82-41C9-4020-9C2B-007C6000D283    ARTI    22150012, 22150017
44899B82-41C9-4020-9C2B-007C6000D283    CASH    NULL
76C6D696-55E7-4CA5-A1AA-0F0DB446D9A4    ARTI    22150018, 22150012, 22150011
76C6D696-55E7-4CA5-A1AA-0F0DB446D9A4    CASH    NULL
```

If `[TicketID]` and `[Type]` are in table `Line` and `[Code]` in table `Article`, `LEFT JOIN` must be used ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cf21/1/0)):

```
SELECT [TicketID], [Type]
    , [Code] = stuff(
        (
            SELECT ', '+ [Code] 
            FROM Line l2
            LEFT JOIN Article a ON a.ID = l2.ArticleId
            WHERE [TicketID] = l1.[TicketID] AND [Type] = l1.[Type]
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, ''
    ) 
FROM (SELECT [TicketID], [Type] FROM Line) l1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that TicketID and Type come from a table and Code comes from a different table :)

Comment: Just join the 2 table: FROM table1 d2 INNER JOIN table2 ON...

Comment: Could you please edit your example so I can clearly see this? I am not sure where to put the INNER JOIN

Comment: You should know how to join t2 table. This is basic SQL. What are your table names and the column name?

Comment: Line: TicketID and Type
Article: Code

Comment: how do you link a row from Line to rows in Articles? Which column(s)?

Comment: Line.ArticleId = Article.ID

Comment: see update and fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cf21/1/0